# Django Template how to set the selected value to the drop down box

Tags: django, django-templates

```
    <select id="_count_id">
        {% for item in list_count %}
            <option value="{{ item }}" {% if item==count %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ item }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Um using the above code to set the selected value to an html drop down though it wont work. count is a numnberical value and an item is any value from 1 to 99 . I cannot figure out where did i do anything wrong . Can any one help? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure the items are actually integers, rather than strings containing digits? Where is `list_count` coming from?

Comment: list count is an array containing integers

Comment: for cnt in range(0,100):
        list_count.append(cnt)

Comment: can you try to replace "item == count" with "item == 2" and see what happens?

Comment: What error do you catch?

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when running it

```
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '==count' from 'item==count'
```

If changing it to item == count (with spaces around '=='), it works.